# Need to remove some characters in the text in active document

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator

Here I had made a script to write equations with superscript.

The input maybe

a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}
The Required output is

a2+b2=c2
Since stackoverflow is not allowing me to put lengthy code I had put it here. Please look this link.

https://forums.adobe.com/message/10331066#10331066

Also I am getting an error in line number "32".

Comment: Why do you need the {} around the characters? What is the error?

Comment: you can use use replace `"a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}".replace(/[{}^]/g , "")`;

Comment: {} are needed so that, I could know where should I make the characters to superscript. @epascarello

Comment: because you can not match the characters after it? Or is it more than just numbers? aka 2^{x+2}

Comment: Also you never say what the error is. What is the error message

Comment: That wont work here @N.Jadhav

Comment: This is scripting in adobe illustrator. It won't show any error message. It only shows where errors are..
@epascarello